# A question about an autocorrelation function of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, covariance, correlation

Let $X= (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ be a strictly stationary process with $E[X_t]=0$ for all $t$. We know that the autocorrelation functions is given by
$$\gamma_X(h)= E[X_0 X_h  ],\quad h > 0$$
Now consider $X_1= (X_{t;1})_{t \in \mathbb Z}$, $X_2= (X_{t;2})_{t \in \mathbb Z}$, $X_3= (X_{t;3})_{t \in \mathbb Z}$,... infinite copies of $X= (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$. Copies of $X= (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ means that $\{X_{j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$, where $X_j = (X_{t;j})_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ , is i.i.d. acording to $X=(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$. So, consider de following random sum:
$$Y_t = \sum_{j=1}^N X_{t;j}, \quad N \sim \hbox{Poisson}(\lambda)$$
Note that this is not a Compound Poisson random process, because $N$ is fixed and does not depend on $t$. Besides this, $\{X_{j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ are independent of $N$.

Note that $(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ is stationary and
$$E[Y_t]= \lambda E[X_t]=0, \quad \forall t \in \mathbb Z$$
*So I want to find the Autocovariance Function of* $Y=(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$:
$$\gamma_Y(h)= E[Y_0 Y_h  ]$$
*in terms of $\gamma_X(h)$, the autocorrelation function of $X= (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$*.

Comment: What if you do the calculation $E[(\sum_{i=1}^NX_{0,i})(\sum_{j=1}^NX_{h,j})]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
E\big(Y_0Y_h\,\big|\,N\big)&=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^NE\big(X_{0;j}X_{h;k}\big)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^NE\big(X_{0;j}X_{h;j}\big)\\
&=N\gamma_X(h)\ .
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
E\big(Y_0Y_h)&=E\big(E\big(Y_0Y_h\,\big|\,N\big)\big)\\
&=E\big(N\gamma_X(h)\big)\\
&=\lambda\gamma_X(h)
\end{align}

Comment: Why $\sum_{k=1}^N E\big(X_{0;j}X_{h;k}\big)= E\big(X_{0;j}X_{h;j}\big)$? Note that for $t$ fixed, I have that $(X_{t;j})_{j=1}^\infty$ is i.i.d.  So $E[X_{t;j_1} X_{t;j_2} ]=0$ for $j_1 \neq j_2$. In your case, we have don't have $t$ fixed. So, I think that   $\sum_{k=1}^N E\big(X_{0;j}X_{h;k}\big)= N  \gamma_X(h)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: I was assuming that the processes $\ (X_{t;j})_{t\in\mathbb{Z}}\ $ and $\ (X_{t;k})_{t\in\mathbb{Z}}\ $ are *independent* for $\ j\ne k\ $, in which case $\ X_{t;j}\ $ and $\ X_{s;k}\ $ will be uncorrelated for *all* $\ s,t\ $, not just $\ s=t\ $. If that's *not* the case, then $\ E(X_{s;j}X_{t;k})\ $ could be pretty much any function of $\ s,t,j,k\ $ satisfying $\ E(X_{s;j}X_{s;k})=\gamma_X(|k-j|)\ $ and $\ |E(X_{s;j}X_{t;k})|\le$$\,\sqrt{E(X_{s;j}^2)E(X_{t;k}^2)}\ $.  You won't *necessarily* then have $\ E(X_{0;j}X_{h;k})$$\ =\gamma_X(h)\ $.

Comment: If you want $\ X_{0;j}\ $ and $\ X_{0;k}\ $ to satisfy this last equation for $\ j\ne k\ $ you would need to specify that as an extra condition, and then, of course, $\ X_{0;j}\ $ and $\ X_{0;k}\ $ could not be independent whenever $\ \gamma_X(|j-k|)\ne0\ $.

Comment: Dear, you are absolutely correct. The copying processes are independent in the sense you described. I was defining this independence marginally. I'll correct the question and accept your answer. Before that, let me try to justify the null correlation between $X_{t,j}$ and $X_{s,k}$ in the following comment. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If the processes $(X_{t;j})_{t\in \mathbb Z}$ and $(X_{t;k})_{t\in \mathbb Z}$ are independent, then any finite dimensional vectors are independent, i.e., taking $(t,s)$, we have $(X_{t,j}, X_{s,j} )$ and $(X_{t,k}, X_{s,k} ) $ are independent vectors. But any continuous functions of these vectors will remain independent. We then apply the projections $P_1(x,y)=x$ and $P_2(x,y)=y$ respectively, so $X_{t,j}$ and $ X_{s,k}$ are independent. Consequently not correlated. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, I think that argument works.  I'd consider the independence of $\ X_{t;j}\ $ and $\ X_{s;k}\ $ to be an "obvious" consequence of that of $\ (X_{t;j})_{t\in\mathbb{Z}}\ $ and $\ (X_{t;k})_{t\in\mathbb{Z}}\ $. If I'd been asked to justify that statement, I'd have used an argument somewhat different from yours, but I think yours is also fine.

Comment: Can you help-me? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620726/a-question-about-an-autocorrelation-function-of-a-stochastic-process-general-ca